# PureScript - What is a newtype?

Tags: purescript

The PureScript handbook defines an exercise as follows:

> Define a Show instance for Point. Match the same output as the showPoint function from the previous chapter. Note: Point is now a **newtype** (instead of a type synonym), which allows us to customize how to show it. Otherwise, we'd be stuck with the default Show instance for records.
> (https://book.purescript.org/chapter6.html)

However, no information about what a *newtype* is is provided.

What is a newtype? What is it for? Why does it work here, but not type?

Comment: Seems you missed [this](https://book.purescript.org/chapter5.html#newtypes) in chapter 5!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newtype is just a wrapper around one(or more) type. We usually use it to expose a predefined or already available type as a new type.

There are lot of useful things we can do with newtype, one of them is specified by the author in the chapter you've shared above.

When you specify

```
type Point = 
  { x :: Number
  , y :: Number
  }
```

You can't actually define your own type class instances(e.g show instance) as `Point` is just a type synonym for Record type which is predefined in Prim module of purescript.

So you wrap it with newtype, and make it a user defined type. Now you can derive whatever instance you want.

You can also use it to create more strict values. For example, you want to create a type name, when its size is less than 6, you want to emphasize a error.
So what you do is,

```
type Name = Either String String
```

then you create a function,

```
type Name = Either String String 
createName' :: String -> Name 
createName' name 
 | (length name) >= 6 =   (Right name)
 | otherwise          =   (Left "Invalid Name")
```

you're happy now. But this doesn't restrict the other developer from doing something like

```
 myName :: Name
 myName = (Right "a")
```

So how you can let the `Name` to be created only by the function?

1. By Only importing the function.
2. By not importing the `Name`

The problem is you can't do 2nd step, as `Name` is just a type synonymn.

`name :: Name` is same as `name :: Either String String`

so you wrap the `Either String String` with a newtype

```
 newtype StrictName = MkName (Either String String)
 createName :: String -> StrictName 
 createName name 
    |  (length name) >= 6 =  MkName (Right name)
    |  otherwise          =  MkName (Left "Invalid Name")
```

now you only import the function and the StrictName(without its construtor)
e.g

```
module Data.MyTypes.Name
(StrictName,createName)
```

Now there's no other way to create a StrictName value without using the createName function. (this is also doable with ADT types, but I prefer newtype)

Newtype are also used to handle [orphan instances](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/OrphanInstance.md) and many more useful things.

> Note : Newtype adds runtimes overhead as theres one more wrapper
> around the original type.

Comment: Where do you get that final quote from, about runtime overhead. My understanding, admittedly based on more experience with Haskell than with Purescript, is that newtypes add NO runtime overhead, and this is also [stated](https://book.purescript.org/chapter5.html#newtypes) in the Purescript book. The whole point about only allowing types with one constructor and one field is to allow to losslessly convert from one to the other, which means the compiler can easily remove the conversion.

Comment: @RobinZigmond it can in theory, but it doesn't always do that in practice. PureScript is way less aggressive than Haskell when it comes to optimizations and inlining, which matters for intrinsics (e.g. `T 1 > T 2` would be compiled as `Ord_T.greater(1)(2)` while `1 > 2` would be compiled as `1 > 2`, which is one heap allocation and two function calls less) and second-order situations, e.g. for `T <$> [1,2,3]` the `map` call will not be eliminated. That is not to say there are no plans to improve this, but right now this is the reality.

Comment: thanks @FyodorSoikin - so I take it that that quote from the book: "In fact, the values of a newtype have the same runtime representation as the underlying type, so there is no runtime performance overhead." is simply false, at least in the situation you've described?

Comment: Yes, pretty much false.

Comment: FeelsBadMan....